# How many integer numbers on the interval $[1,10^n]$ have a digit $0$ on its usual decimal representation

Tags: combinatorics, integers

I would know the answer if the question asked about the algorism $3$
the solution would them satisfy a recurrence relation:

$$T_{n+1} = 9T_n + 10^n$$

well, I suposed this case would obey a similar recurrence relation and conjectured that the answer is $$\frac{19^{n-1}+1}{2}$$

I would like confirmation/disproof of this as I haven't thought about any combinatorial argument to obtain this result.

Comment: What is an algarism?

Comment: digit , for example 10 has an algarism 0, 100 has 2, 1000 has 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy : you have $9^n$ numbers without $0$ between $10^{n-1}$ and $10^n$. Indeed, you need to choose, for each on the $n$ digits, one non-zero digit.

This means that there is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 9^k = \frac{9^{n+1}-1}{9-1}-1 = \frac{9^{n+1}-9}{8} = \frac{9}{8}\left( 9^{n}-1 \right) $$

numbers without $0$ less than $10^n$

So there are

$$10^n - \frac{9}{8}\left( 9^{n}-1 \right)$$

numbers with a zero between $1$ and $10^n$

Comment: So the answer is $10^n - \frac{9^n - 9}{8}$

Comment: @onlyme :  Yes, I answered the opposite question, sorry.

Comment: I think you made some mistakes in the formula.

Comment: @dREaM : yeah, I misscounted the numbers of digits ;), it's correct now

Comment: Yeah, I think it is good now, although question asks for the numbers that do have a  zero.

Comment: @dREaM : done :)

Comment: The expoent on 9 is n too but I got the idea, thank you both

Comment: @onlyme : this was a copypasta error, but thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 3):

There are $9^n$ integers of $n$ digits with no zeroes, since there are $9$ options for every digit. This tells us there are $9^n+9^{n-1}+9^{n-2}+\dots 9$ integers between $1$ and $10^n$ that have no digit zero.

We have $9^n+9^{n-1}+\dots+9=\frac{9^{n+1}-1}{8}-1$ integers between $1$ and $10^n$ with no zeroes. Therefore there are $10^n-\frac{9^{n+1}-1}{8}+1$ with at least one zero.